# AV Receiver with 3-5 TOSLINK ports and remote (NOT IR) control

Tags: audio, amplifiers

I am looking for the not very expensive receiver. The main things I am interested in:

- 5.1-7.1 support
- As much TOSLINK (optical) ports as possible
- Possibility to control it without IR (RS232, TCP/LAN, etc)

Can you please suggest some models, I'll try to research our market ...

UPDATE: there is no too much requirements from my side. I have currently ONKYO TX-SR 601 E receiver that is 435×175×432mm and that's more or less max size I need. The price I'm trying to hit is ~400$ for the used unit.

Comment: Do you have a hard price ceiling? What about any size requirements? Do you have anything else you can add to your question that might help us search?

Comment: @Cfinley just made an update

Comment: Thanks. Keep in mind that used units are tricky for us. If an answer links to a specific item, that answer will be deleted (eventually) as it will not help future readers. However, a link to a new unit should have all of your requirements, but might be too expensive, leaving you with the exercise of finding a seller.

Comment: @Cfinley new units might be OK also. So, I believe that the new one would cost 600$ and I would try to find used one then.